# Git: get number of changed lines per day

Tags: git

I'd like to make a diagram of added/removed/changed lines in a git repository per day and/or week. I do *not* want to count the number of commits.

Is there a tool that can produce such charts (gitstats does not)? Or, with which git command I can produce an output which i could parse easily?

Thank you!

Answer (score 38):

Maybe something like this:

```bash
$ git diff --shortstat "@{1 month ago}" 
 7 files changed, 29 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
```

(As you can see, I tried this on a pretty stale repository.)

Note that this will compare the current working directory to what the current branch pointed to one month ago on your local machine.

**Edit**: To get stats for all commits on the branch `master` in a certain date range, you can use

```bash
git log --after=2011-01-01 --before=2011-01-31 --format=format: --shortstat master
```

Comment: Cool - didnt know you could do that with git

Comment: Thank you, but maybe I should make my question more concrete: I want to have daily/weekly stats for EVERY day since the initialization of the repository.

Comment: @ernestoche: The problem is -- what commits would you like to include?  History isn't linear in git, so you have to specify somehow what to include.

Comment: It would suffice if it would count all changed/removed lines in 'master'. In fact, the most simple example I could think of: A repository, where only I commit to, and where there is only one branch (master), and I want to see how 'much' work I have done each day (but which could be one large commit a day or a lot of small ones, so I want to count lines/changes).

Comment: @ernestoche: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: same answer for `git diff --shortstat "@{1 month ago}"` and `git diff --shortstat "@{1 day ago}"`! Does not work!

Comment: @Chalist It may not do exactly what _you_ were expecting, but it does "work"  – it will compare the current working directory to what the current branch pointed to one month ago or one day ago _on your local machine_. It's very well possible that the state of that ref was the same one week ago and one month ago, so you will get the same result.

Answer (score 27):

```bash
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                         
a=""                                                                                                                                                                                
b=""                                                                                                                                                                                
for i in $(seq 1 10)                                                                                                                                                                
do                                                                                                                                                                                  
    b=$(git diff --shortstat "@{ $i day ago }")                                                                                                                                     
    if [[ "$b" != "$a" ]]; then                                                                                                                                                     
        echo $i "day ago" $b                                                                                                                                                        
    fi                                                                                                                                                                              
    a=$b                                                                                                                                                                            
done
```

#### output

```
1 day ago 2 files changed, 144 insertions(+), 21 deletions(-)
3 day ago 2 files changed, 227 insertions(+), 73 deletions(-)
```

[the gist](https://gist.github.com/2137751)

Comment: Great!!   `git diff --shortstat "@{1 day ago}"`

Comment: Is there a way to get the shartstat for between a time period? That is, specifying "3 days ago" and "after 2 days"

Answer (score 6):

I just needed the accumulated diffstat for a period of time in the repository without relying on the reflog (as the repo was freshly cloned). Thus i came up with this:

`( eval $(git log --pretty="%H" --since="2 day" |  while read line; do if [[ -z ${first} ]]; then first=${line}; echo "export first=${first}"; fi; echo "export last=${line}"; done; ) ; git diff --stat ${first} ${last}; )`

you can easily modify the "2 day" to get something else :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a bash script that calculates the total number of changed lines per week:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ds() {
  date --date="$1 weeks ago" +%Y-%m-%d
}
BRANCH=master # your branch here

echo "Week,Lines Changed"
for week in {80..1}
do
  # git log outputs lines like:
  # 11        10      path/to/your/file.java
  #  => add first two columns with awk
  lines=$(git --no-pager log --after=$(ds $week) --before=$(ds $(($week - 1))) --format=format: --numstat $BRANCH | awk '{s+=$1; s+=$2} END {print s}')
  echo "$(ds $week),$lines"
done
```

Output is in CSV format and looks like:

```
Week,Lines Changed
2016-12-21,5989
2016-12-28,17179
```

Answer (score 5):

My version of above scripts, for stats per days, with nice formatted output ...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Calculate num of changed, new lines on git per days (show your productivity)

ds() {
  date --date="$1 days ago" +%Y-%m-%d
}

echo "GIT changes stat: Date, Total lines modified (New added, Changed)"
for week in {13..0}
do
  # git log outputs lines like:
  # 11        10      path/to/your/file.java
  #  => add first two columns with awk
  lines_all=$(git --no-pager log --after=$(ds $week) --before=$(ds $(($week - 1))) --format=format: --numstat | awk '{s+=$1; s+=$2} END {print s/1}')
  lines_chg=$(git --no-pager log --after=$(ds $week) --before=$(ds $(($week - 1))) --format=format: --numstat | awk '{s+=$1;} END {print s/1}')
  lines_new=$(git --no-pager log --after=$(ds $week) --before=$(ds $(($week - 1))) --format=format: --numstat | awk '{s+=$2}  END {print s/1}')
  #echo -e "$(ds $week): $lines_all \t\t(new: $lines_new, \tchanged: $lines_chg)"
  printf "%10s: %10s \t\t(new: %10s, \tchanged: %10s)\n" $(ds $week) $lines_all $lines_new $lines_chg
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Adapting from [gnmerritt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41473489/1700191), this script will generate number of lines of add and delete for each calendar day.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ds() {
  date --date="$1 days ago" +%Y-%m-%d
}

BRANCH=master # your branch here

echo "Date,LinesAdded,LinesDeleted"
for day in $(seq 1 10)
do
  lines=$(git --no-pager log --after=$(ds $day) --before=$(ds $(($day - 1))) --format=format: --numstat $BRANCH  | awk '/([0-9]+).*([0-9]+).*/{s+=$1; t+=$2} END {printf "+"; printf s;printf ",-"; printf t;}')
  if [[ "$lines" != "+,-" ]]; then
      echo "$(ds $day),$lines"
  else
      echo "$(ds $day),0,0"
  fi
done
```

[(Link: Github Gist)](https://gist.github.com/yuan3y/1f7f297ca17f29670963a5d48f6dd967)

Answer (score 1):

Updated to work on macOS.

```bash
ds() {
  if [ "${OSTYPE:0:6}" = "darwin" ]; then
    date -v-${1}d +%Y-%m-%d
  else
    date --date="$1 days ago" +%Y-%m-%d
  fi
}

echo "GIT changes stat: Date, Total lines modified (new, changed)"
for week in {13..1}; do
  lines_all=$(git --no-pager log --after=$(ds $week) --before=$(ds $(($week - 1))) --format=format: --numstat | awk '{s+=$1; s+=$2} END {print s/1}')
  lines_chg=$(git --no-pager log --after=$(ds $week) --before=$(ds $(($week - 1))) --format=format: --numstat | awk '{s+=$1;} END {print s/1}')
  lines_new=$(git --no-pager log --after=$(ds $week) --before=$(ds $(($week - 1))) --format=format: --numstat | awk '{s+=$2}  END {print s/1}')
  printf "%10s: %10s \t\t(new: %10s, \tchanged: %10s)\n" $(ds $week) $lines_all $lines_new $lines_chg
done
```